# How do I get the values of arguments passed inside a func() argument in GO?

Tags: reflection, go, arguments, func

I am trying to create middleware inside routes and wondering how one can get the values of arguments passed inside a func() argument.

For example:

```
func (c appContainer) Get(path string, fn func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)) {

    // HOW DO I GET THE VALUES OF rw AND req PASSED IN fn func()?

    c.providers[ROUTER].(Routable).Get(path, fn)
}
```

I looked through the reflection docs but it's not clear to me or perhaps there is a simpler way?

## **EDITED (SOLUTION)**

It turns out reflection is not needed, as suggested by Adam in his response to this post, as well as Jason on [his golang-nuts reply](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/B4T1dwCIUZk/bvcrEgkL7rEJ) to my question.

The idea is to create a new anonymous function which then intercepts the parameters passed to it for modification/enhancement before calling the original function.

This is what I ended up doing and it worked like a charm, which I am posting in case it helps someone else:

```
type handlerFn func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)

func (c appContainer) Get(path string, fn handlerFn) {
    nfn := func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        c.providers[LOGGER].(Loggable).Info("[%s] %s", req.Method, req.URL.Path)
        fn(rw, req)
    }
    c.providers[ROUTER].(Routable).Get(path, nfn)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple answer: you don't. Not at that place at least

the variables `rw` and `req` make first sense if the function `fn` is called. (or a function that calls fn, which probably will have `rw` and `req` variables)

In your case it is probably where `appContainer` uses the routes configured

To better understand how middleware concept works a simple example can be found here: https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

you might want to scroll down to "Introducing Function Literals and Closures"

Comment: Good answer. I'd also suggest the OP look at https://justinas.org/writing-http-middleware-in-go/ and http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware - it looks like they're currently working against the grain. If you have to reach to `reflect` just to write HTTP middleware something might be askew!

Comment: Thanks for your response Adam! I edited my original question to show how I ended up implementing it.